# Visualizing and interpreting a graph structure on a lattice

Tags: graph-theory

EDIT: Previous section of the question for context: 
The Ising model currently used in electromagnetism, statistical mechanics, as well as image processing is associated with the state space
$$S = (−1, +1)^E$$
I'm currently working on an assignment and one of the questions contains the following statement.

$$E = \{1, . . . , L\} \times \{1, . . . , L\}.$$

The lattice $E$ is equipped with the following
graph structure:

$$j_1 = (i_1, i_2 + 1)$$ $$j_2 = (i_1 + 1, i_2)$$ $$j_3 = (i_1, i_2 − 1)$$ and $$j_4 = (i_1 − 1, i_2).$$

EDIT:around some state$$ (i_1, i_2) ∈ E.$$Two neighbors $$i, j ∈ E$$ are denoted by $$i ∼ i'$$

Does anyone know what the graph looks like or how to interpret it?

Cheers

Comment: I'm a little unclear on your construction -- what is the vertex set and what is the edge set of this graph? Also, I've edited your question to make use of MathJax typesetting. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for guidelines.

Comment: From my educated guess the vertex set apperas to be j1,j2,j3 and j4. However, It doesn't appear to be clear. I have added some extra information for context (which may also inc extra information I may have omitted).